# Prove two norms with identical induced metric are equal.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $v$ be a real vector space. Suppose $\| \cdot \|_1,\| \cdot\|_2$ are two norms on $v$ such that their induced metrics on $v$ are identical. Prove that $\|\cdot\|_1 = \| \cdot\|_2$.

Hi guys, I have done this question before in class, but now can't remember where to begin and how to solve it fully. I think we have to begin by a contradiction?

If someone can help me solve it completely, I really appreciate it.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is the formula for the metric induced by $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Comment: it is a general question, no formula is given. so I believe it has to be solved generally with what is given.

Comment: I will rephrase @kimchilover's question. *What* is the metric induced by the norm $\|\cdot\|_1$? That is, what does “induced metric” *mean*?

Comment: That is not given, I assume it may be euclidean metric

Comment: Note that the above commenters are asking you questions, and although they phrase it as a question, the actually know they answer and are trying to get you to answer your own question by trying to make you say what is the definition of "induced metric".

Comment: What does induced metric mean? If youre asking that then you shoulnt be on this question.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum To whom is your comment addressed?  If to me, I think user580918 has stated my excuse.

Comment: My point is, its reasonable to assume the most trivial of definitions. If youre informed on the topic at all then the naive definition should be sufficient for a naive question.  Dont you think?  Asking the OP to define every word in the dictionary is a bit absurd and its just an excuse to not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry guys, I dont know who is following who... the guy below is on right track at answering this question. add your comments there.... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
Ok, so you have 2 norms, their induced metrics $d_1(x,y) = \|x-y\|_1$ and $d_2(x,y) = \|x-y\|_2$ agree for all $x,y$. In other words,
$$
\|x-y\|_1 = \|x-y\|_2, \quad \forall x,y \in v.
$$
Can you find a very special value to use for $y$ in the above formula to simplify it and make it look like what you need?

Comment: y can be zero?......

Comment: @AsgharBakerdar fantastic. Can you now take this to conclusion using $y = 0$ and complete the problem?

Comment: wouldn't that then imply \|x\|_1 = \|x\|_2? Is it really just two lines? I wanted to represent it in a rigorous way, as it is going to be marked.

Comment: @AsgharBakerdar yes, indeed. short and sweet

Comment: sweet, many thanks @gt6989b

Comment: @AsgharBakerdar you are welcome, happy to be of help